# What are the requirements around account de-registration?

Tags: ios-appstore

When one uploads an app on the App Store, do you need to include a delete account (or even log out account) option? Is it required to wipe that data off the server?

Comment: I don't understand your question. To upload an app to the App Store, you have to be a member of Apple's Developer program (info at developer.apple.com), and your membership should give you access to updating, managing, and deleting your apps. But I'm not sure what account you want to delete, or how that is connected to app development.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe so. In my app [Free Bitcoin](https://itunes.apple.com/app/apple-store/id954157737?pt=49113808&ct=apple.stackexchange.com&mt=8) I don't provide a delete option (one can contact me through the app and I will manually remove their account), and log out is performed by removing and reinstalling the app. The app was approved by Apple without any trouble.